# React-admin - how should be the exposed data from the backend - hasura/graphql

Tags: graphql, react-admin, hasura

i'm using `ReactAdmin`(3.19.6) with `ra-data-hasura`(0.2.0) dataprovider
it works for tables but don't for Actions

when the ReactAdmin  start a message appears

`Unknown resource apikeyReceived. Make sure it has been declared on your server side schema. Known resources are comunicazioni, comunicazioni_aggregate, ping, ping_aggregate, profiles, profiles_aggregate`

`apikeyReceived` is an action resource and probably it isn't in the aspected shape from ReactAdmin (it miss some property or metadata that reactadmin needs)

```
<Admin dataProvider={dataProvider} >
      <Resource name="comunicazioni" list={ListGuesser} />
      <Resource name="apikeyReceived" list={ListGuesser} /> 
</Admin>
```

i think this message is popped out when react admin execute the introspection query.
Is there a way i can intercepr this "event" and override or add something?

Comment: Did you manage to get around this @pinale?